# Why is ChangeNotifierProvider.value not updating its builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a lot of data objects. Each with a `ChangeNotifier`. So I want to update the smallest area possible. What must be changed to make this example work?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyData _myData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myData = MyData(title: 'Really my data');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Provider Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<MyData>.value(
          value: _myData,
          builder: (BuildContext _, Widget __) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_myData.toString()),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('edit'),
                  onPressed: () => _myData.incrementCounter(),
                ),],);},),),);}}

class MyData with ChangeNotifier {
  String title;
  int counter = 0;

  MyData({
    this.title,
  });

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    print('counter=$counter');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTitle(String newValue) {
    title = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String toString() => '$title - $counter';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `ChangeNotifierProvider<MyData>.value` you provided MyData to the Widgets below it, but you don't use it anywhere. To watch changes in MyData use for example a `Consumer` widget.
Here's the fixed code using consumer:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyData _myData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myData = MyData(title: 'Really my data');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Provider Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<MyData>.value(
          value: _myData,
          builder: (BuildContext _, Widget __) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Consumer<MyData>(
                  builder: (context, mydata, child) {
                    return Text(_myData.toString());
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('edit'),
                  onPressed: () => _myData.incrementCounter(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyData with ChangeNotifier {
  String title;
  int counter = 0;

  MyData({
    this.title,
  });

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    print('counter=$counter');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTitle(String newValue) {
    title = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String toString() => '$title - $counter';
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `myData.toString()` instead of `_myData.toString()`

Comment: @yellowgray: Good point for Hettikas answer.
@Hettika: Is there any "Provider" variant which combines providing an already existing `ChangeNotifier` like `MyData` with a `Consumer`?

Comment: I tried to replace the combination of `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `Consumer` with `Provider.value` but got the error message:
```
Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (MyData). This is likely a mistake ... consider using: -ChangeNotifierProvider that handles the update mechanism. So either the message is wrong or there is a bug in `ChangeNotifierProvider`

Answer (score 0):

```
          void main() {
            runApp(ForProvider());
          }

          class ForProvider extends StatefulWidget {
           
            @override
            _ForProviderState createState() => _ForProviderState();
          }

          class _ForProviderState extends State<ForProvider> {
            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return MultiProvider(providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<MyData>(create: (context) => MyData()),
              ], child: MyApp());
            }
          }

          class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return MaterialApp(
                home: MyHomePage(),
              );
            }
          }

          class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
            @override
            _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
          }

          class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
            MyData _myData;

            @override
            void initState() {
              _myData = MyData(title: 'Really my data');
              super.initState();
            }

            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Provider Test'),
                ),
                body: Center(
                  child: Consumer<MyData>(
                    builder: (context, myData, child) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Consumer<MyData>(
                            builder: (context, myData, child) {
                              return Text(myData.toString());
                            },
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            child: Text('edit'),
                            onPressed: () => myData.incrementCounter(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }

          class MyData with ChangeNotifier {
            String title;
            int counter = 0;

            MyData({
              this.title,
            });

            void incrementCounter() {
              counter++;
              print('counter=$counter');
              notifyListeners();
            }

            void setTitle(String newValue) {
              title = newValue;
              notifyListeners();
            }

            String toString() => '$title - $counter';
          }
```

Comment: Hi Nitesh. Thanks for your answer. But your approach results in "Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyData> above this Consumer<MyData> Widget...". I suggest to test your answers beforehand unless you are 110% sure they work :-)

Comment: Hi Hajo, i think you have not initialised your provider above your MyHomePage class.
You need to initialise your MyData provider above MyHomePage class like this.
"ChangeNotifierProvider<MyData>(
          create: (context) => MyData())"

Comment: Hi Hajo, I have edited the code, please try to use it.

Comment: Hi Nitesh. Thanks for your support. Your approach is similar to the one from Hettika. You insert a "Provider' before consuming its value. I'm still looking for ONE widget like "Provider.value" which rebuilds when the value changes like "Provider.of" is doing.

Answer (score 0):

A consumer widget as posted by @Hettika is correct, an updated approach is to use `context.watch`

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<Model>.value(
  value: modelInstance,
  builder: (context, _) {
    context.watch<Model>();
    
    return MyWidget();
  },

)
```